# Does a linear model make assumptions about distributions of depended and independent variables?

Tags: r, regression

As the title says, does a linear regression model make assumptions about distributions of depended and independent variables and what should these distributions be for the model to work as expected ?  I have a log normal distribution (or rather a very positively skewed one) for both  dependent and independent variables and I always log transformed them before doing any fitting but came across an article saying that is not necessary. Also just to add to this, I would like to use the model to predict values of individual data points.

Comment: Linear regression doesn't make assumptions about the distributions of DVs or IVs. It makes assumptions about the distribution of the residuals.

Comment: @Roland Not *quite*; it's about errors rather than residuals. If you perform inference (hypothesis tests, confidence intervals, prediction intervals) there's an assumption about the distribution of *errors*, which we can't observe, but for which the residuals are a proxy (and indeed if all the other assumptions hold, may be regarded as an estimate of the errors). To simply estimate a regression doesn't require that assumption, though.